# Woocommerce: Change “add to cart” button color when someone add something in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hope you are doing well, I need the help of my woo commerce site. I want when someone adds the product to the cart and color will be changed immediately to another.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some simple Javascript, then making a PHP function and adding it to your wordpress site. You can add the function to your functions.php file if you know where that is, If not simply install a snippet plugin to do this via WordPress Dashboard.

This is 1 way to do it:

1. Install a Snippets plugin (Example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)
2. Create a function Similar to this (Make Necessary changes if needed, most likely works out of the box though)

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'single_add_to_cart_event_text_replacement' );
   function single_add_to_cart_event_text_replacement() {
       global $product;
   if( ! is_product() ) return; // Only single product pages
   ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           (function($){
                   // You can change the “button.*******” to your css element if it does not work
                   $('button.single_add_to_cart_button').click( function(){

                   // Change the Red to your desired color name or HEX Value   (Example: #000000 is black)
                   $(this).css('background-color','red');
               });
           })(jQuery);
       </script>
   <?php
   ```

   }
3. Finally save and Activate
4. Go to your Single Product page and Click Add to cart :)